# Plotly 3dscatter and colorscale

Tags: javascript, graphics, plotly

I am using Plotly.js through its JavaScript API to plot some 3D scatter plots. It looks fantastic:

[image]

In this plot the colors of the points are based on the z values of the points. If I change this to the x or y values (by changing the data[0].marker.color array), and redraw, things go wrong:

[image]

I expect to see something like:

[image]

No matter if I use **redraw** or **newPlot** again. It looks like once a colorscale is calculated from the data it keeps the same mapping function from data to color. So my question is how can I "invalidate" the colorscale such that things get recomputed when doing a redraw with a new color array.

### update

In the answer from etpinard (thanks!) there is a simple complete example. However this version has already all x,y, and z data nicely scaled between 0 and 1. I.e. it has:

```
function randomArray() {
  var out = new Array(N);
  for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    out[i] = Math.random();
  }
  return out;
}

var x = randomArray(),
    y = randomArray(),
    z = randomArray();
```

My data has different units for x,y and z. I can simulate this with:

```
function randomArray(lo,up) {
  var out = new Array(N);
  for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    out[i] = lo+(up-lo)*Math.random();
  }
  return out;
}

var x = randomArray(0,1),
    y = randomArray(0,1),
    z = randomArray(0,1000);
```

With this version the first plot looks good:

[image]

We color the dots according to their z value. But then when I click on the 'x' button I see:

[image]

I hope this helps to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I believe I can work round this by scaling the data to 0-1 before passing it on to marker.color.

Comment: Yes: always scaling marker.color to a value between 0 and 1 did the trick. Plotly does that for you, but only once in a session.

Comment: Best to restyle the whole `marker` attribute object in this case: http://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/pgbPag

Comment: Thanks! That seems to fix this (without me scaling the color array myself).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try using `Plotly.restyle` for operations of the sort.

Here's an example: http://codepen.io/etpinard/pen/WrxRKO

Comment: Thanks! I think I can reproduce my problem with your simple example by using different scales for x and y. I'll elaborate in the question. Thanks again, I appreciate it.

Comment: See comment above how to repair this: call restyle with a whole new marker object.